# CSocket::Create() returns 0

Tags: mfc, client, connect

I've connecting other process with socket connecting. So I create client socket which is object of CSocket Class. And I call Create method in CSocket class and I make my own program. But It doesn't work in create. It returns 0 value. Please tell me why does this happens.

Here's my brief code

```
CSocket *socket = new CSocket();
if(socket->Create())
   if(socket->Connect("127.0.0.1",0))
     socket->Send(widthCap, sizeof(widthCap));
socket->Close();
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call GetLastError() and look the value up [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I would guess that you have a firewall that blocks your exe. Remember that adding your exe to your firewall exception list will not help as you probably build a new exe every time you hit F5.